# How can I tell why my node app is crashing on Heroku? (HTML, Stripe, Heroku, NodeJS)

Tags: html, node.js, express, heroku, stripe-payments

So, I've developed a website (HTML) that has an embedded payment form from Stripe called Checkout. When you visit the website, it prompts you to enter your credit card information, so the checkout form is working correctly.
The issue I'm having is processing the token once it's created.

I'm extremely new to web development and I've never written server code before so please, bear with me.
I've been following guides ([Process payments with Node, Vue, Stripe](https://scotch.io/@connor11528/how-to-process-payments-with-nodejs-vue-2-and-stripe) & [How to set up Stripe payments with Node.js](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/stripe-payments-with-node/)) and stripes documentation on tokenization to create charges using server-side code ([Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial))

I understand that I have to have Heroku set up to process the charges so I created an account and set up an app from my terminal. I made a new directory that has the modules required (stripe, express, and bodyParser) and I have this code in my server.js file:

[image]

It deploys to Heroku successfully but crashes. This is what is being returned in the console:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Any assistance would be a great help.**

Comment: You'll probably have more luck with your question if you make the title closer to your real problem, eg. How can I tell why my node app is crashing on Heroku?  The credit card bit isn't relevant to the problem and it helps to narrow down your problem as much as possible.

Comment: I don't know much about Heroku but can you get more detailed logs? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#view-logs

Comment: The code and error message should be text and not images. Please copy/paste that into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a vital piece:

```
// Start the server
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + port)
});
```

You don't seem to start the server in your application. This should be in the bottom of *server.js*. You also have to remember to set the port:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

It goes above `app.listen` of course.

I can't tell for sure if that will fix *all* your errors, but you have to start with starting the server first.

Also, remember to check for errors in callbacks. In the callback for `create` you are not doing that. E.g.

```
if (err){
    console.error(err);
    res.json({ error: err, charge: false });
} else {
    // send response with charge data
    res.json({ error: false, charge: charge });
}
```

You are doing `res.send()` whether or not there are errors. I doubt that this has anything to do with the Heroku error though.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was all I was missing